# ui-datepicker not working angular js

Tags: angularjs, datepicker

Am having difficulties getting this date picker to work.

included the javascript files

```
<script src="js/ui-bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="js/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
```

in the index page

in my app project file I inject it

```
 var testing = angular.module("testing", ["common.services", "ui.router", "ui.bootstrap"]);
```

markup

```
<span class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" is-open="opened" datepicker-popup="yyyy" ng-click="open1($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
            </span>
```

main controller

```
angular.module("testing").controller("MainController", ["$scope", MainController]);

function MainController($scope) {
    $scope.opened = false;
    $scope.open1 = function ($event) {
        $event.preventDefault();
        $event.stopPropagation();
        $scope.opened = !$scope.opened;
    };
}
```

but nothing is happening.

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: Where is your ng-model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether you mentioned your complete markup or If this is your complete markup then it is wrong. This is what I use:

```
<input type="text" class="" uib-datepicker-popup="dd-MMMM-yyyy"  ng-model="startDate" min-date="minDate" max-date="cmaxDate" show-button-bar="false" show-weeks="false" is-open="isStartDatePickerOpen" required readonly/>


<span class="input-group-btn">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default inline" ng-click="startDatePickerToggle()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
  </button>
</span>


Controller:
$scope.startDatePickerToggle = function(){
  $scope.isStartDatePickerOpen = true;
};
```